# How can I make $http with authentication?

Tags: angularjs

I have make a POST request to an API and they have basic authentication, how can I tell angular $http POST service to pass my credential while making the post requestion?

Comment: if you already have auth-token, you need [request interceptor](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

Comment: Can set default config such as headers....see `$http` docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add auth interceptor as follows

```
angular.module('interceptors.authInterceptor',[])

.factory('authInterceptor', ['$q', function ( $q) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN;
      return config;
    },
    response: function (response) {
      return response || $q.when(response);
    },
    responseError: function(rejection) {
    }    

  };
}])

.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
}]);
```

Comment: should mention that since this is a whole module it requires being injected in main app module

Comment: Yes, you need to add this module in main app module. Sorry, I missed it.

Comment: Do I need to change anything on my $http.post ?

Comment: No, because you are adding your authInterceptor to $httpProvider.interceptors, all $http request will get added with auth token. You need not to do anything extra for $http.post

Comment: I added the factory you suggested but I still get the authentication error. I did check the call from a server side language and its working fine

Comment: They use basic authentication, do I need to add the Basic in front of the username and password?

Comment: How are your passing username and password in http request ? You need to pass username and password in body of your POST http request.

Comment: Got it working... I had a missing : in between. I guess it was late and I was tired :) thank you for the help